# karma test case for url redirecting

Tags: karma-runner

Karma test case run through Istanbul.

```
$scope.processChkBoxes = function(listOptions){
        var urlAltered = false;
        $scope.myData.data  = '{}';
        url = URLHolder;
        $scope.myData.loadDataFlg = true;
        $scope.myData.noDataFlg = false;
        if(listOptions[0] == true){      
            Iif(urlAltered == true){
                url = url + "&showSubCust=true";
            }else{
                url = url + "?showSubCust=true";   
                urlAltered = true;
            }                              
        }
        if(listOptions[1] == true){
            Eif(urlAltered == true){
                url = url + "&showSettled=true";                        
            }else{
                url = url + "?showSettled=true";
                urlAltered = true;                        
            }
        }
        if(listOptions[2] == true){
            Eif(urlAltered == true){
                url = url + "&showPendingVeh=true";                         
            }else{
                url = url + "?showPendingVeh=true";
                urlAltered = true;                        
            }
        }
        Iif(listOptions[3] == true){
            if(urlAltered == true){
                url = url + "&showActiveVeh=true";                          
            }else{
                url = url + "?showActiveVeh=true";
                urlAltered = true;                        
            }
        }
        VehicleListService.getVehicleList(url).then(function(data){
            $scope.myData.data  = data;
            Iif($scope.myData.data ==undefined){
                    $scope.myData.noDataFlg = true;  
            }
            $scope.myData.loadDataFlg = false;

        });        
    };

$scope.search = function() {
$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
```

but its not showing full coverage.

Can any one help on this by writing a test case

Comment: What have you done so far? What specific part is not covered?

Comment: If  and else statement..... i am posting t again the code snippet  from browser which is run by istambul

Comment: it('2. check the checkbox group', function() {
        var listOptions = [ true, true, true ];
        $scope.processChkBoxes(listOptions);
        expect(vehiclelistServiceMock.getVehicleList).toHaveBeenCalled();
        listOptions = [ false, false, false ];
        $scope.processChkBoxes(listOptions);
        expect(vehiclelistServiceMock.getVehicleList).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: i wrote this but still its have not cover fully

Comment: can we grt any support